# createProvider is not exported from react-redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to create multiple distinct Redux stores, for that am using `createProvider()` method in 'react-redux'.

I have installed the latest react-redux version(7.1.0), but am getting the error like *"createProvider is not exported from react-redux"*. When i gone through the node modules, i couldn't able to find the `createProvider` inside the src of react-redux. Is it a version issue or did i miss something in the code. I have shared you the following code snippet as :

*Provider.js*

```
import { createProvider } from "react-redux";

export const STORE_KEY = "myComponentStore";    
export const Provider = createProvider(STORE_KEY);
```

*TestComponent.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import Mycomponent from "./MyComponent";

import { Provider } from "./Provider";

const reducer = {};

const initialState = {
  title: "multiple store"
};

const store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

class TestComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Mycomponent />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
export default TestComponent;
```

*Mycomponent.js*

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

import { connect } from "./Connect";

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.title}</div>;
  }
}

export default connect(function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    title: state.title
  };
})(MyComponent);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `createProvider` you can just import Provider directly from react-redux. If you want to use multiple stores just create multiple store instances and it should just work

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/4b9cecefde7b3e4c6344d3277c46ad0471c4bbfe/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L109 

storeKey has been removed and does not do anything. To use a custom Redux store for specific components, create a custom React context with React.createContext(), and pass the context object to React Redux's Provider and specific components like: <Provider context={MyContext}><ConnectedComponent context={MyContext} /></Provider>. You may also pass a {context : MyContext} option to connect

Answer (score 3):

Seems like it is [deprecated](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1132) and [removed](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/pull/1000/commits/d97cf239fbed322fd73397799e9649d759093041) since V6

Answer (score 1):

Your store could be something like this:

```
// store.js

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from './root-reducer';

export default createStore(rootReducer);
```

And that "rootReducer" is a combination of different reducer files:

```
//root-reducer.js

import SomeReducers from './reducers/some-reducers';
import AnotherOne from './reducers/another-one';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  SomeReducers,
  AnotherOne,
})

export default rootReducer;
```

Then your store is used in the `index`

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./storage/store";
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root')
);
```

But it still just one `store`

Answer (score 0):

In [documentation](https://redux.js.org/api/createstore), it says

> Don't create more than one store in an application! Instead, use
>   combineReducers to create a single root reducer out of many.

So one provider, one store and multiple reducers are the correct(recommended) way to use redux. Create one global provider for your application and define your reducers for that provider. You can use data selectors for your components.

For this information probably dev team decided to deprecate `createProvider` functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create multiple distinct Redux stores

It's fine to have multiple and distinct Redux stores in a single React application. Just don't use `createProvider()` for it. The two approaches to having multiple independent Redux stores are:

- Use Redux [sub-apps:](https://redux.js.org/recipes/isolating-redux-sub-apps)

```js
SubApp5.js
----------
const store = createStore(reducer)

return {
  <>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <MyTable />
    </Provider>
  </>
}
```

With this approach multiple Redux stores will coexist.

- Use multiple SPAs inside a single React application - see [crisp-react](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react). With this approach multiple Redux stores will *not* coexist.
  When you build crisp-react, it creates a React application with 2 SPAs and you can add Redux to each SPA. Then you can switch from one SPA (and its Redux store) to another SPA and its store.